# Compare Wordpress Staging and Development

Tags: staging

I have a Wordpress site that has 12 WPML languages, 15 CPT, and 150 ACF-Fields. On our development site, we performed some content testing and upgrades. To do this, we replicated the staged site's content to the development server and worked on it. In the interim, items on the live site had altered. Now comes my question. What is the quickest way to tell the difference between the live and development sites?